# Oracle DataSource Doubts?

Tags: datasource

1. When we get a connection using datasource say `oracleDatasource` . 
   Lets say during programming, some developer does not close the connection 
   explicity.
    Will that connection be returned to connection or will it 
   be considered as connection leak?
2. As it is said, datasource is created, deployed, and managed separately(by appserver) from the applications that use it. There are two ways in which we can create datasource

   1. From appserver admin console.(I understand that datasource can be managed by appserver here)
   2. Second way is to create datasource in your pragramme like 
      `Datasource ds = new OracleDataSource();`
      But how will datasource be managed by appserver api in this case as we are creating it in our programme?

Comment: Hi, I have used the datasource connection in my web application, I deployed it JBOSS, But in the code I havent closed the connection explicitly.When the first request went and response came to the browser,JBoss says on the console, like Connection is not closed, Closing the connection for you !! So which means the connection wont be leaked.... And the app server manages the DS , I'm not aware